# Different MVC4 action based on GET variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a way to get MVC4 to call different actions based on a GET variable in the URL?

For example, let's say I have the following two actions.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitCrash(CrashReport rawData)
{
  return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitBug(BugReport data)
{
  return View();
}
```

Is there a way I can use the following URLs to have MVC4 'choose' which action to call?

```
http://MySite/Submit?Crash (calls 'SubmitCrash')  
http://MySite/Submit?Bug (calls 'SubmitBug')
```

**UPDATE:**
I am very much aware that I can use actions / urls the way they are, and do stuff with routing to make it happen (which is what I am doing now), but I am really interested in the GET vars part of the question.

Comment: Is `http://MySite/Submit/Crash` an option for you? You could achieve this with a custom route table entry.

Comment: yes, its how I do it now, but that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as neat as it could be, but you may use 'root' action for this:

```
public ActionResult Submit(string method)
{
  return Redirect("Submit"+method);
}

public ActionResult SubmitCrash()
{
  return View();
}

public ActionResult SubmitBug()
{
  return View();
}
```

**Edit**
I have extend ActionNameAttribute to meet your needs, so you may write this:

```
//handles http://MySite/Submit?method=Crash
[ActionNameWithParameter(Name = "Submit", ParameterName = "method", ParameterValue = "Crash")]
public ActionResult SubmitCrash()
{
  return View();
}

//handles http://MySite/Submit?method=Bug
[ActionNameWithParameter(Name = "Submit", ParameterName = "method", ParameterValue = "Bug")]
public ActionResult SubmitBug()
{
  return View();
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ActionNameWithParameterAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string ParameterName
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string ParameterValue
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public ActionNameAttribute(string name, string parameterName, string parameterValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "name");
        }
        this.Name = name;
        this.ParameterName = parameterName;
        this.ParameterValue = parameterValue;
    }
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return string.Equals(actionName, this.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && string.Equals(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get(ParameterName)
                , this.ParameterValue
                , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, and wordy.  I am coming to the conclusion that MVC4 doesn't have a built in way to handle my scenario huh?

Answer (score 2):

Why not create routes to do this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SubmitCrash",
            url: "Submit/Crash",
            defaults: new
                {
                    Action = "SubmitCrash",
                    Controller = "NameOfController",
                });

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SubmitBug",
            url: "Submit/Bug",
            defaults: new
                {
                    Action = "SubmitBug",
                    Controller = "NameOfController",
                });
```